# Solution to equation modulo p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Under the assumptions that $$p\cong 1 \mod 5$$ and $$g = 2(c+c^{-1})+1$$ where $c$ has order $5$ modulo $p$. I need to show that $g^2 \cong 5 \mod p$.
I have that $$g^2=4(c^4+c^3+c^2+c)+9$$
I know that if I can somehow remove the $c^3$ term, I can solve the equation through quadratic reciprocity. Can anybody give me some hints?

Comment: See the answer to the Second Question at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3013787/ . My $z$ is your $c$; my $w = 1 + 2z + 2z^4$ is your $g = 2\left(c+c^{-1}\right) + 1$ (because $z^4 = z^{-1}$, since $z^5=1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to note here is that $c$ has order $5$ modulo $p$; this implies that $c^5 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, and factoring gives $(c-1)(1+c+c^2+c^3+c^4) \equiv 0 \pmod p$. So either you will have $c=1$, which is handled trivially, or you will have $c+c^2+c^3+c^4 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, allowing you to simplify your expression.